# Как в go-sql-driver использовать переменную в db.Query/Exec?

Tags: mysql, golang

```
func test(id int) string {
   //
   rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM db.texts WHERE `id` = (id) values (?)", id)
  //
}
```

При использовании id, выведет ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильный sql запрос, поэтому и появляется ошибка. Чтобы передать переменную нужно использовать вопросительный знак, в этом вы правы, но вы написали его немного не там. VALUES не нужен для того, чтобы сделать SELECT. Правильный запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM db.table_name WHERE id = ?", id)
```